# Intermittent Cannot connect to shibd process, a site adminstrator should be notified

Tags: apache, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

We have a shibboleth native SP 2.5.4 that's been running for a few years without any issues. Yesterday I had to update a certificate for one of the IDP. Since that restart I've been getting intermittent errors:

Cannot connect to shibd process, a site adminstrator should be notified.

Errors appear to occur in bursts as shown by these number of errors per minute:

```
 nb | time
 58 Sep 22 09:56
 82 Sep 22 10:53
 82 Sep 22 11:16
 80 Sep 22 11:17
 89 Sep 22 11:37
 71 Sep 22 11:38
130 Sep 22 11:43
 47 Sep 22 11:44
```

Restarting httpd and shibd didn't resolve the issue. SElinux is disabled.

In /var/log/shibboleth-www/native_warn.log I have:

```
2020-09-22 11:54:13 ERROR Shibboleth.Listener [15798] shib_check_user: socket call (connect) resulted in error (2): no message
2020-09-22 11:54:13 WARN Shibboleth.Listener [15798] shib_check_user: cannot connect socket (21)...
2020-09-22 11:54:13 CRIT Shibboleth.Listener [15798] shib_check_user: socket server unavailable, failing
2020-09-22 11:54:13 ERROR Shibboleth.Apache [15798] shib_check_user: Cannot connect to shibd process, a site adminstrator should be notified.
```

Memory and CPU look good to me:

```
top - 12:08:08 up 25 days, 22:33,  2 users,  load average: 1.01, 1.03, 1.01
Tasks: 294 total,   1 running, 293 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32880188k total,  4712256k used, 28167932k free,   426772k buffers
Swap:  5242876k total,        0k used,  5242876k free,  1993996k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
16876 apache    20   0  370m  10m 4160 S  0.7  0.0   0:00.20 httpd
17418 shibd     20   0 4894m  58m 8084 S  0.7  0.2   0:01.46 shibd
 2401 root      20   0 3116m 270m  19m S  0.3  0.8 128:41.88 cylancesvc
17519 apache    20   0  370m  10m 3948 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.12 httpd
17766 apache    20   0  370m  10m 3872 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.13 httpd
```

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Did you restart SP after restarting idP? I assume you are getting these errors in SP.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have any static certificate entry along with path to idP metadata.